# How to prefix the application url in apache?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, symfony-1.4

My Project is done in Symfony 1.4 framework (PHP). Its configured on my machine and I can access the application as http://localhost:8082.

All my urls are like

xhttpx://localhost:8082/login
xhttpx://localhost:8082/logout
xhttpx://localhost:8082/new/item
xhttpx://localhost:8082/item/edit/id/34 etc.

Now i want to change all my urls to

xhttpx://localhost:8082/pink/login
xhttpx://localhost:8082/pink/logout
xhttpx://localhost:8082/pink/new/item
xhttpx://localhost:8082/pink/item/edit/id/34 etc.

i.e. append pink after the base url (http://localhost:8087).

I want to achieve this without modifying the Symfony 1.4 files (e.g. routing.yml etc).

I guess we can achieve this by modifying the httpd.conf and by writing appropriate rewrite rule.

Note: please read xhttpx as http, as stackoverflow was not allowing me to post hyperlinks.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in the root, containing this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8082/pink/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This tells Apache to route all traffic in the folder that the .htaccess is in to /pink/.

Comment: this is resulting in "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: Perhaps it is a consequence of redirecting within the domain localhost. I know this works when you redirect from one domain to another (so presumably when you release your project it will work). I'll look for an alternative for the meantime.